# import.io selecting css class with xpath that contain certain value/character

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, import.io

```
<div id="mDetails">
<span class="textLabel">Bar Number:</span>
    <p class="profileText">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</p>
<span class="textLabel">Address:</span>
    <p class="profileText">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY<br>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY<br>United States</p>
<span class="textLabel">Phone:</span>
    <p class="profileText">123465798</p>
<span class="textLabel">Fax:</span>
    <p class="profileText">987654321</p>
<span class="textLabel">Email:</span>
    <p class="profileText">regina@rbr3.com</p>
<span class="textLabel">County:</span>
    <p class="profileText">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</p>
<span class="textLabel">Circuit:</span>
    <p class="profileText">YYYYYYYYYY</p>
<span class="textLabel">Admitted:</span>
    <p class="profileText">00/00/0000</p>
<span class="textLabel">History:</span>
    <p class="profileText">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</p>
```

im trying to select the email only if its available cause when i use `//*[@class="profileText"]`it returns everything with this class , i want only to return when `@` is present in the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the adjustment to the input XML to change both `<br>` to `<br/>` (otherwise it's not valid XML) the following XPath selects all `p` elements that have the class `profileText` and contains `@`:

```
//p[@class='profileText'][contains(.,'@')]
```

returns

```
<p class="profileText">regina@rbr3.com</p>
```

In case you only want to get the value, you can use `string()`:

```
string(//p[@class='profileText'][contains(.,'@')])
```

returns

```
regina@rbr3.com
```

Note that `string()` would only return the value of the first match, while the first XPath returning the `p` elements returns all matches.